# Maps and polymorphism

Tags: c++, dictionary, polymorphism

I have a `base class Adapter` that `extends` two classes `Device1` and `Device2`. I want to store both type of object in the same map so i tried this

```
std::map<std::string, Adapter*> deviceMap;

bool Circuit::add(Adapter *wrapper, std::string &name)
{
    if(deviceMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, Adapter*>(name, &wrapper)).second == false)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Where I use this function like this

```
Circuit circ;
circ.add(new Device1(*param*), "dv1");
```

But i get an error message saying

```
main.cpp:13: error: no matching function for call to 'Circuit::add(Device1*, const char [4])'
     circ.add(new Device1(*param*), "dv1");
                                                ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use `public` inheritance when you derived your types?

Comment: yes, `class Device1 : public Adapter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
circ.add(new Device1(*param*), "dv1");
```

attempts to bind a non-const reference to a temporary. Try

```
bool Circuit::add(Adapter *wrapper, const std::string& name)
```

---

Another small issue is in the line

```
if(deviceMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, Adapter*>(name, &wrapper)).second == false)
```

where `&wrapper` is used instead of `wrapper` (`wrapper` is an address already).

Comment: that didn't help, i got `error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, Adapter*>::pair(const string&, Adapter**)`

Comment: Don't we need to pass `wrapper` instead of `&wrapper` when we create the `pair`?

Comment: Maybe you are right, but shouldn't i pass the address

Comment: Like when you do this `Type * ptr = &obj`

Comment: `wrapper` _is_ an address already: `bool Circuit::add(Adapter *wrapper, std::string &name)`

Comment: You are completely right, can you add that to your anwser